# Repaint issue with Chrome on a retina screen when clipping fixed element with scrollable content

Tags: scroll, fixed, repaint, clip, retina

When on a retina screen; clipping a fixed element causes Chrome/Opera to stop repainting the (with overflow enabled) scrollable content. I think this is due to a bug in Blink, but I'd like to know if anyone knows a solution to this issue.

[I've reproduced the problem on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uz0sndfz/1/), but the actual problem can only be viewed on a retina screen with a Blink browser (Chrome of Opera). As soon as I move my window to my 2nd (non-retina) screen, the problem fades away and everything behaves as expected. I've included a few images to illustrate the problem for those without a retina screen.

**The HTML/CSS**

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.text-block {
    width: 50%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    p {
        padding: 20px;
    }
}
.clip {
    clip: rect(10px,300px,300px,10px);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
.scroll {
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
    <div class="clip scroll">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="text-block">
                <p>This is what's clipped</p>
            </div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
            <div class="text-block">
                <p>This is what's clipped</p>
            </div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
            <div class="text-block">
                <p>This is what's clipped</p>
            </div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: This is the starting situation on both screens]
[image: On my 2nd monitor (non-retina), the content scrolls as expected]
[image: On my retina screen, the clipped content isn't being repainted]